# Using Peewee ORM to generate data for graphs

Tags: python, sql, orm, peewee

I'm building a web app which allows professors to input assignments for students to follow along with, an interactive syllabus if you will. One of the sections of a course page displays progress.

I have built a pie graph component which I'd like to populate with data:

```
pie_chart(
    title, # name of chart
    percent, # percentage of assignments completed
    count, # how many assignments completed
    total # how many assignments total
)
```

I'm using the Peewee ORM to retrieve this data from my assignments table:

```
class Type(BaseModel):
    name = CharField() # Homework, Test, Final, etc.

class Assignment(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    due_date = DateField()
    type = ForeignKeyField(Type)
    course = ForeignKeyField(Course)
```

I need the following from the database and I'm not sure how to accomplish it with Peewee. Getting the name, and total should be simple. But I need to compare the due_date to today's date to see how many of the assignments are completed.

### Name       Total    Completed

Final      2        0
Homework   23       12
Test       4        2

My pie chart output will look something like this if it matters:

```
Homework
|XXX-------|
3 of 10 complete
```

**UPDATE**

I've got a query that does almost everything I need. Can anyone help me take it the rest of the way?

Here's the query:

```
select t.name,
        count(a.type_id) as total,
        (
            select count(id)
            from assignment a
            where a.course_id = 7
            and a.user_id = 3
            and a.due_date < date()
            group by a.type_id
            order by a.type_id
        ) as completed
from assignment a
inner join type t on t.id = a.type_id
where a.course_id = 7
and a.user_id = 3
group by a.type_id
order by a.type_id
```

And here's the result using the sample data below:

```
Homework, 8, 6
Test, 4, 6
Final, 2, 6
```

This is really close, but I would expect the completed column to be specific to the assignment type.

Here's some sample data from the Assignment table

```
id name
------------------------
9, Chapter 1, 2014-11-01
10, Chapter 2, 2014-11-08
11, Test on chapter 1-2, 2014-11-15
12, Chapter 3, 2014-11-19
13, Chapter 4, 2014-11-22
14, Test on chapter 3-4, 2014-11-25
15, Midterm - Chapter 1-4, 2014-11-25
16, Chapter 5, 2014-11-25
17, Chapter 6, 2014-11-25
18, Test on chapter 5-6, 2014-11-25
19, Chapter 7, 2015-01-09
20, Chapter 8, 2015-01-11
21, Test on chapter 7-8, 2015-01-13
22, Final - Chapter 1-8, 2015-01-15
```

The following is the best I could come up with for now. I'm hardcoding the "completed" column because I can't get it right:

```
Assignment.select(
    Type.name,
    fn.Lower('1').alias('completed'),
    fn.Count(Type.id).alias('total'),
).join(Type).where(
    Assignment.course==self,
).group_by(Type.id).order_by(Type.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that your subquery returns more than one row - you should add 'and a.type_id = t.id' to the subquery's where.

Comment: Ran, thanks for pointing that out, that does indeed fix that issue! I'd rather avoid the subquery to begin with though. Do you have thoughts on how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about dates in python, and peewee in particular is that you can compare them in a pretty intuitive way. Behind the scenes dates are typically represented as number of seconds since some date in 1970. Here's an example of querying by date with peewee:

```
today = datetime.today()
query = Tweet.update(is_published=True).where(Tweet.creation_date < today)
query.execute()
```

In this example the `Tweet` class is just one with a boolean `is_published` attribute, and a datetime `creation_date` attribute.

Something closer to your example would be:

```
today = datetime.today()
query = Assignment.select().where(Assignment.due_date < today)
```

But I'll try not to completely give the answer away.

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have today handy in a python value (and you're using sqlite) you can use `fn.date('now')` to get today. Similar functions exist for MySQL or Postgresql.

Comment: So part of what I'm wanting to figure out is how to best get both total value and value already passed.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what that means.

Comment: Sorry Cole. I realized that was lacking in detail. I need to get the "total" number of assignments for a give type, as well as the number of assignments which have already occurred. Using my example above I would need to determine that 3 assignments have occurred before today's date, and there are 10 total assignments. I'm not sure of the best approach to achieving that. Perhaps a subquery?